# Flash AS3 Multiple If statements

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

Is it possible to do multiple if statements? I'm trying to get something like the following to work:

```
stop();

continueb_lilmine3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, overHandler);

function overHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
      if(MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell4.currentFrame == 3)
      if(MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell2.currentFrame == 3)
      {MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(5);

  }else{
{gotoAndStop(3);
}}}
```

The ifs seem to work, but the else does not. It says stuck on frame 2 of the continueb_lilmine3 MC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off.  An `if` statement should have a code block (or a single line of code) after it.

**[Edit]**

I believe your code seems to work, because according to the compiler, your first `if` statement is followed by exactly one statement -- the if/else construct. So in effect, perhaps your code is doing this:

```
if(MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell4.currentFrame == 3)
{
    if(MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell2.currentFrame == 3)
    {
        MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(5);

    }
    else {
        {gotoAndStop(3);} // unnecessary brackets here?
    }
}
```

And thus the else never executes.

**[end]**

**[Edit #2]**
Here is what you are probably after:

```
if (MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell4.currentFrame == 3 && MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell2.currentFrame == 3)
{
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(5);
}
else
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, that makes sense. How would I combine these two exactly? I'd have the one if, then ?? 

if(MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell4.currentFrame == 3)
(MovieClip(root).lilmine_cell2.currentFrame == 3)

Comment: Not sure what you want, is the condition that both MC's have currentFrame == 3, or either one has currentFrame == 3?